# Per Infinispan Cache Properties

Tags: infinispan, infinispan-10

We have some generic code that operates on the caches in an Infinispan cache container. The code identifies certain caches for which a certain operation has to be performed by a custom property. The cache container and caches are configured through `infinspan.xml` or the Infinispan subsystem in WildFly.

Previously we would set a custom property on the datastore of the cache. With Infinispan 10+ this is no longer possible. We would have to implement a custom persistence store in order to set arbitrary properties on a cache. This seems like overkill especially since our caches are not persistent.

Is there a way to achieve this from an `infinspan.xml`, eg. without putting a custom object under a well known key in the cache?

**Edit**

The previous configuration looked something like this:

```xml
<local-cache name="stackoverflow-cache" configuration="default-configuration">
  <data-container>
    <property name="custom-property-key">custom-property-value</property>
  </data-container>
</local-cache>
```

With version 10 of the Infinispan schema this is no longer supported.

Comment: you you elaborate what is missing for Infinispan 10 for you custom properties? Where are you setting those? Is it an Infinispan configuration property?

Comment: @pruivo I added a sample configuration that we used

Comment: Are you using a custom `DataContainer`, like `<data-container class="my class">`? If so, custom data container is not supported anymore. If you just need some properties in the configuration, I may have a workaround for you, to add them... just let me know.

Comment: @pruivo no, we're not using a custom `DataContainer` and our caches are not persistent. We just set some properties to identify certain caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example of how you can set some custom properties in the configuration [here](https://github.com/pruivo/playground/tree/master/custom-config). It isn't trivial...

If you are using Infinispan server, you need a Jar with your classes and put it in `server/lib` folder.

Let me know if it fits your use case (I hope I didn't misunderstand it).

ps. since you control the parser, you can set your own XML structure if you want.